# Oracle SQL Developer - Connecting to a connection

Tags: database, oracle, connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created two connections DatabaseTest and sectest2.

When accessing DatabaseTest:

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12528, TNS: listener: all

appropriate instances are blocking new connections

vendor code 12528

When accessing sectest2:

I have facing an error when trying to access the connections that I have created by following the videos posted in Oracle sql developer. The error says

IO Error: The network adapter could not establish the connection Vendor Code 17002

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-12528, TNS: listener: all
>
> appropriate instances are blocking new connections

Reason behind this might be any of the following: 
1. Database is in restricted mode. If so, below command will resolve the problem: 
sqlplus "/as sysdba" 
alter system disable restricted session; 
2. Database might be in such state that, it is not accepting connection. For example, in starting mode. Not yet open. Please check that. 
Please check by running the below command:
select instance_name, status, database_status from v$instance;

> IO Error: The network adapter could not establish the connection
>   Vendor Code 17002

Check whether listen is up or not.

> lsnrctl status;